# Obtener los días lunes entre un rango de fechas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Quiero obtener los días lunes entre un rango de fechas con una consulta, los ejemplos que he visto sólo dan ejemplos en sql server.

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo pero solo me trae los lunes de un sólo mes:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY) AS Date 
FROM (
            SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS row 
            FROM (
                        SELECT 0 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                        SELECT 6
            ) t1,
            (
                SELECT 0 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 3 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 4 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 6
            ) t2, 
            (
                SELECT @row:=-1
            ) t3 LIMIT 31
        ) b
WHERE DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
AND DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL ROW DAY)) = 2
```

Espero me puedan ayudar y quizás haya una consulta mas sencilla de realizarlo.

Saludos

Comment: A lo mejor en vez de limit 31 podrías poner limit 365, pero igual el cruce entre t1 y t2 sólo te genera 49 filas dummy

Comment: Sí ya lo intenté, pero no me funcionó! @amenadiel

Comment: no te funcionaba porque estabas generando sólo 36 filas dummy, y limitando a 31 resultados. No alcanzabas a generar suficientes filas como para llegar al primer lunes de febrero. Las dos respuestas que te pusieron generan suficientes filas dummy para recorrer el año completo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Opción 1

Si tiene una tabla con filas suficientes para satisfacer tus necesidades (*en este caso, mínimo 365*), puedes utilizarla como base para obtener lo que necesitas.

Mi tabla `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` tiene `12035` filas.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL row DAY) AS date
FROM (
  SELECT @row := @row+1 AS row
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, (SELECT @row := 0) t
) T
WHERE DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL row DAY) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
AND DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL row DAY)) = 2
```

### Opción 2

Úne dos tablas sin condición y el número resultante de filas se multiplicará.
Esto creará `2^20` filas (`1.048.576`).

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL row DAY) AS date
FROM (
 SELECT @row := @row+1 AS row
 FROM (SELECT @row := 0) t
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t1
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t2
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t3
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t4
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t5
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t6
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t7
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t8
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t9
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t10
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t11
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t12
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t13
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t14
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t15
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t16
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t17
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t18
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t19
 JOIN (SELECT true UNION ALL SELECT true) t20
) T
WHERE DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL row DAY) BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
AND DAYOFWEEK(DATE_ADD('2017-01-01', INTERVAL row DAY)) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Para obtner los lunes entre un rango de fechas puedes usar el siguiente codigo:

```
set @fecha1  = '2016-10-14';
set @fecha2  = '2017-3-2';

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT DATE(ADDDATE(ADDDATE(@fecha1, INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY)) AS DIASENTREFECHAS
FROM (
SELECT a.a
FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
) a
JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
WHERE 
@i < (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, @fecha1, @fecha2 )) ) AS DIAS
WHERE dayofweek(DIASENTREFECHAS) = 2
```

Lo que hace es generar todas las fechas entre las 2 fechas dadas en el select interno poniendolas en una columna llamada DIASENTREFECHAS y despues en el select externo filtramos solo las que sean Lunes con `dayofweek(DIASENTREFECHAS) = 2`

Pruebala en fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/95200/2